# vue js equals strings

Tags: javascript, vue.js

why `filter` is not working with `this.userId` but working with hard code value `"admin"`? How can I fix this?

```
computed: {
    UidMessages: function() {
       return this.Messages.filter(function(m) {
         return m.to == this.userId;
     })
   }
 },
```

And it does work =>

```
computed: {    
   AMesseg: function() {
     return this.Messages.filter(function(m) {
       return m.to== "admin"
     })
   }
},
```

I think it's because of the comparison of the strings

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `arrow` function as [mentioned in answer by @Satyam Pathak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63338076/9695286) or you can declare object outside of `this.Messages.filter` and use that object in condition. like below.

```
computed: {
  UidMessages: function() {
     let userId = this.userId;    // declare and assign userId value.
     return this.Messages.filter(function(m) {
       return m.to == userId;     // use userId variable for condition.
   });
 }
}
```

**P.S.** Refer [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

`this` getting `undefined` here because it's not binding to your `fn`. Use `arrow syntax`  to lexically bind `this` to the `fn` and it should work

```
 computed: {
    UidMessages: function() {
       return this.Messages.filter(m => {
         return m.to == this.userId
     })
   }
  },
```